# How do write into a text file, without the lines connecting after you increase the file size?-Java

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am using BufferedWriter to write text into a notepad.txt file. The program writes the text with a new line for every sentence, but when I increase the size of notepad, all the lines connect to each other. How do I stop that from happening?

```
    bw.write(Text);   
    bw.close();
```

Because after the lines connect to each other, the program cant read from the file any more, because the line structure is different and doesn't recognize it.

Comment: "The program writes the text with a new line [...]" Your little code snippet exactly shows that you write the text _without_ a newline. With calling `newLine()` on your `BufferedWriter` you will get what you want, exactly as @MrunalGosar's answer explains.

Answer (score 1):

Use bw.newLine() to insert a new line character, so that it will not connect

Comment: It already insets a new line, but when I increase the notepad widows size, all the lines start to connect to fill the space.

Comment: @danny try to open in wordpad

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the output you are getting and the output you expect.

Comment: Open that doc in notepad++ and turn on wordwrap.

Comment: Do as the writer of this answer suggested, call `bw.newLine()`. This inserts your platform sequence of characters for a new line, which is `"\r\n"` on Windows. You're in all likelihood only writing a `"\n"` as part of your string, and when you open that in Notepad, you see one line, because haven't written the windows new line sequence in your file.

Answer (score 0):

How about the PrintWriter class in java?

It will be one of better option for the situation.

The usage of the class looks as follows,

```
public void writeFile() {
    String someText = "some of my text";
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(
                new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("myout.out")))));

        out.println(someText);
        out.flush();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {

        if(out != null) out.close();
    }

}
```

Too lat answer,

Regards,